# To swipe back quickly in ReactNative

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, gesture, react-native-navigation, react-native-gesture-handler

I am creating an app that swipes back in ReactNative, is it possible to increase the speed of the swipe back?

Simulator

- iOS11

I already tried https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#gesturevelocityimpact.
I could not find the effect.

lib.

```
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs":"6.3.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "6.0.10",
"@react-navigation/native-stack":"6.6.2",
"@react-navigation/stack":"6.2.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the cardStyleInterpolator solved the problem.
Reference
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#cardstyleinterpolator
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/stack/src/TransitionConfigs/CardStyleInterpolators.tsx

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).